# Force DNS Server on network

Tags: dns, firewall, untangle

We are using an Untangle firewall that requires users to have their DNS servers pointed to it, which by default it is, as this is set in the router.

However, users can change their DNS servers and therefore avoid the firewall. Is there any way in which this can be fixed. Can I force everyone on my network to use a specific DNS server (not just per computer)?

Comment: "Is there any way in which this can be fixed. Can I force everyone on my network to use a specific DNS server?" - How do you currently assign the user's permissions?  You didn't provide us any details on what OS you are using.  If you have an AD server then specify that fact by editing the question.

Comment: I would like to globally force a DNS server on the whole network, not per computer.

Comment: You have already done that by configuring your clients to get their DNS from your router though.  Your comment doesn't answer my question.  When you update your question, and it contains the information I politely asked for, ping me

Comment: I use Untangle and haven't had to do this before. You'd be looking for a DNS intercept feature and asking in their forum would be the best place to get a quick response. However, you can certainly use the firewall to block port 53 so that users are unable to use any other external DNS server. If they try, they'll just break their computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hardly a firewall if using your own DNS server gets around it. I'd call that something like a "filtering DNS relay", not a firewall.

If you want your DNS server to be the only one people can easily reach, set your firewall (assuming it really does have traditional firewall features) to block egress to port 53 for both TCP and UDP.